# Sharepoint 2013 deploying files using a module to subsites

Tags: 2013, file, module

I wanted to deploy files to lists already created. This works but only for the top level site.
I used the following elements.xml

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Sjabloon" Url="Sjabloon/01. Informeel bijpraten">
    <File Path="ModuleResources\Sjabloon\__Agenda Beschrijving.agenda.pdf" Url="__Agenda Beschrijving.agenda.pdf" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
    <File Path="ModuleResources\SitePages\Home.aspx" Url="ModuleResources/SitePages/Home.aspx" />
  </Module>
</Elements>**
```

On feature activation on a subsite it gives an error in the ULS that the list "Sjabloon"can't be found.. Which isn't true.
Further more the feature is scoped to web.

Comment: Is Sjabloon a document library or a list? Is the relative url of the list Lists/Sjabloon? In that case, try this: `<Module Name="Sjabloon" Url="Lists/Sjabloon/01. Informeel bijpraten">`

Comment: Already fixed it failed because of the Home.aspx which already exists (of course)  Had to add ReplaceContent="true"  now it works..

Comment: Hmm after testing I saw that sjabloon really doesn't exist at subsite because sharepoint seems to rename the listname to Sjabloon1 Sjabloon2   etceter. I also created an cleaning feature but after recreating the list that name is sometimes locked.. So above code works actually